# Shorten repeat assignments with coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

I'm parsing http POST requests with express.js and just need to pull in all the variables that were sent by the client.  Right now it looks like this:

```
token   = req.body.token
amount  = req.body.amount
product = req.body.product
link    = req.body.link
address = req.body.address
```

Is there a way to shorten these repeat assignments with coffeescript syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [destructured assignment](http://coffeescript.org/#destructuring) for such things:

> **Destructuring Assignment**
>   To make extracting values from complex arrays and objects more convenient, CoffeeScript implements ECMAScript Harmony's proposed destructuring assignment syntax. When you assign an array or object literal to a value, CoffeeScript breaks up and matches both sides against each other, assigning the values on the right to the variables on the left.

In your case:

```
{ token, amount, product, link, address } = req.body
```